# Status code 406 using Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to format the response from a GET method i followed the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) tutorial.I can get json response but not xml it returns a status code 406.

This is my Startup class :

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            // Use the default property (Pascal) casing
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

        });
        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            // requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
        });
```

Controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[FormatFilter]
public class TableController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpGet("values.{format}")]
    public ActionResult<List<Table>> Get()
    {
        return _context.Table.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering my own question because i found the answer i just needed to replace the

> AddXmlSerializerFormatters()

with

> AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()